# Stata reference variable by column number

Tags: stata

Can I refer to variables by the number of the column they reside in?

---

Here's why I want to know: for each observation, I have three vectors in Euclidean space, so my columns are

```
obsID | v1b1 v1b2 v2b1...v5b4 | tv1b1 tv1b2 tv2b1...tv5b4 | nv1b1 nv1b2 nv2b1...nv5b4
```

where the `|` are included simply for readability. My variable names look like those above, but I don't know the naming pattern ahead of time. I can get the length of each vector as `ng = (c(k) - 1)/3`, so if I could refer to variables by column, it would be straightforward to write a loop to find Euclidean distances, e.g., from `v` to `nv`.

I know there are other ways to go about calculating the Euclidean distance (like reshaping the data; or extracting the varnames from `2/(ng+1)` and doing a `foreach` loop on them), but if there is a way to reference variables by column number, I would like to know it.

Comment: Here is an old [post](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-03/msg00073.html) on the topic. The solution is basically retrieving the variable list in its order with `ds`, and then referencing the ith variable through something like ``loc v `v' `:word `i' of `r(varlist)''`` or ``loc v=word("`r(varlist)'",`i')``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can imagine several ways:

1. Some code like

   ```
   sysuse auto, clear

   quietly ds
   local myvar `:word 5 of `r(varlist)''

   display "`myvar'"

   <do something with local myvar>
   ```

   will get you a way of working with the fifth variable without knowing its name. You can use loops and define list of variables in this way. This is basically a response from http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-03/msg00073.html.
2. Convert your database to a `matrix` and work with that. See `help svmat` and `help matrix`.
3. Use a Mata function like `st_varname()`. See `help Mata` and `help mf_st_varname`. See also `help m4_stata`.

But I haven't encountered situations in which this is a natural way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two ways of doing it (without renaming variables and with):

```
sysuse auto, clear

/* Without Renaming Variables */
unab varlist: _all
local K: word count `varlist'

forvalues v=1/`K' {
    local v`v': word `v' of `varlist'
    di "v`v' is `v`v''"
}


matrix dissim ED1 = `v2' `v12', L2 variables
matrix list ED1


/* Rename Variables */
rename * v#, renumber
matrix dissim ED2 = v2 v12, L2 variables
matrix list ED1
```